# iLNumerics isn't displaying my 3d plot - the plot remains 2d

Tags: c#, ilnumerics

The code is this:

```
        //we need to render locations.
        ILArray<float> ourPositions = ourSimulator.getStars();

        var scene = new ILScene();
        var plotCube = scene.Add(new ILPlotCube(twoDMode: false));

        var ourPosBuffer = new ILPoints();
        ourPosBuffer.Positions = ourPositions;

        plotCube.Add(ourPosBuffer);
        plotCube.FieldOfView = 120;
        plotCube.LookAt = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);

        iLStarChart.Scene.Configure();
```

Now, an earlier version of this code (in a different solution) still uses 3.3.2, and

```
        var plotCube = scene.Add(new ILPlotCube(null, false) )
```

I've tried both on a 3.3.3 version, and neither displays a 3d plot. Instead, it's a 2d grid. What am I doing wrong here?

(the points are:

```
        <Single> [3,4]
        -32.00000 37.00000 36.00000 38.00000 
        54.00000 107.00000 106.00000 130.00000 
       -81.00000 -16.00000 -124.00000 -226.00000
```

)

EDITED: Missing ) on the 3.3.2 example

EDITED: Reduced some of the non critical code out of the example.

The expected result is that I have a 3d plot with x,y and z axis. I'm getting a 2d plot. No z axis. I've verified the points (the  is a ToString)

A sample run provides this: https://www.dropbox.com/s/imiw8tbe0lh8q9x/2DPlot.png

Comment: Please reduce you example! Be more specific. Describe the expected and the observed result!

Comment: I've reduced the example.

Comment: Are you able to rotate the plot cube with the left mouse?

Comment: Make sure there is only one plot cube in the scene and that it is set to twoDMode =false. Start with a toy example and add your configuration step by step. When does the error appear?

Comment: There is only one plot cube. I've generated basic plot code by generating a dummy float table. It's still 2D. Step debugging says that it's being passed a 3x3 right now. I cannot rotate it with the left mouse.

Comment: Btw. The Z axis is there but hidden. You can prove by: plotcube.Projection = Perspective.

Comment: Are you able to rotate the plot cube with the left mouse?

Comment: With both Projection=Perspective and AllowRotation=yes, no. Should I try without Projection=Perspective? (without it is no, actually. I did a quick test)

Comment: Sorry, I am lost. I dont get your problem. It seems, that everything is fine, except that you cannot rotate the plot with the mouse? Please provide a small *runnable* test code which we can use in order to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Would you want the code that's only for the render rather than the full project as-is?

Comment: We need the code needed to reproduce your problem. It should be possible to provide a small code example which we can compile and run. Than, describe what you expect and what does not work. Thanks.

Comment: ... so, uh. When I packaged the code to send it worked just fine. The problem? When I placed the control, I may have hit something because it turns out enabled = false. This fixed it.

Comment: (In totally unrelated news, I feel like an absolute moron right now.)

Comment: That's why requesting a running example sometimes is the best help we can support ... :) Glad you solved it.

Answer (score 1):

This is a rough example of what i used, you need to add an "ILSurface" to the plotcube

```
        //Replace and make sure they are all added in order
        Single[] zs = [All Zs]
        Single[] xs = [All Xs]
        Single[] ys = [All Ys]           

        //create array of points               //something like below
        ILArray<float> points = ILMath.zeros<float>(xs.Length/s, s, 3);
        points[":;:;0"] = zs;
        points[":;:;1"] = xs;
        points[":;:;2"] = ys;            

        // construct a new plotcube and plot the points
        scene = new ILScene();
        cube = new ILPlotCube(twoDMode: false);
        surface = new ILSurface(points, colormap: Colormaps.Jet);


        //set scene properties
        scene.Add(cube);

        //display cube in scene
        ilPanel1.Scene = scene;
```

Comment: by looking at your code I realised you should just replace the "points ILArray in my code with you ILArray<float> ourPositions